# Is trusted SSL communication between local machines on a network possible

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, csr

My question is: Is it possible to have a computers on a network communicate with commercial SSL certificates ?

I want to have computer A on my network host a website: A Springboot Webserver application I wrote.

I have computer B on the same network also and I want to access a webpage on computer A via HTTPS (SSL).

I have no problems doing self signed certificates.

But I want to use an SSL Certificate from a Certificate Authority like Comodo. 
I've been trying it with Let's Encrypt free SSL Certificates and I haven't been able to get it to work so far.

Thanks

Comment: Of course it's possible. What is your real question?

Comment: Can it be done with a publicly trust CA? If so, how is it setup? This page I believe says that it can't be done. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-CA-issued-SSL-certificate-for-internally-accessed-LAN-IP-address-web-application

Comment: Sure it can be done for a publicly trusted CA, for **real domain names**. It can't be done for IPs, `localhost`, made-up domains that aren't registered, or things like `.test` / `.internal` / `.dev` etc. TLDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get a certificate from a publicly trusted CA for domain names which are public. If the names you use match this requirement then you can get certificates for these, otherwise not. Once you have the certificates the setup of the certificates for the internal web servers is no different from the setup on external web servers.

Comment: Yep. A wildcard cert for `*.internal.example.com` is a good approach here.

Comment: @ceejayoz: not really. If you would use the a wildcard certificate (and probably the same on all machines and thus also the same private key) it would be enough for somebody to get access to one machines certificate and key in order to impersonate any other machines in the network.

Comment: OP's scenario is a browser on A visiting a website hosted on B. Something more complicated is fine in a more complex scenario, but it'll work fine in what OP describes.